# How do I make a variable be the server name with and different on each server with discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a warn system where if you type blocked words, you get warned in dms.
I want to use my discord bot across multiple servers of mine, however I want it to say "You have been warned in {server name} for {reason}" but I do not know how to make a variable that is the server name

```
    var array = ['blocked words one','blocked words two','etc']
    if(msg.author.hasPermission('VIEW_AUDIT_LOG')) return;
        if(array.some(w => `${msg.content.toLowerCase()}`.includes(`${w}`))) {
            msg.delete();
        msg.reply('Please do not send flagged words, you have been muted for 2 minutes')  
        }
        var servername = **I do now know how to do it**
        var reason = (`*__Warning from Auto-Mod__** | **__Reason:__** Using filtered words | **__Your Message:__**\n${msg.content}`)
        var filterEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`You were warned in ${servername}`)
```

*(I still have to send this to the user, but I just wanted to show you where I needed help)*

Answer (score 0):

The get the server's name from a message, you can use

```js
message.guild.name
```

Here, we're taking the "server" (on discord.js we name it guild) and then taking its name. So really what you're trying to do is:

```js
let servername = message.guild.name
```